# How to traverse using `startsWith()` in gremlin?

Tags: graph, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlinpython, tinkerpop

How to traverse using `startsWith()` in gremlin?

```
g.V('6b4e7018-a2d1-45fd-a1ce-78efe4c96c33').bothE(startsWith('live_at_'))
.elementMap().toList()
```

or

```
g.V('6b4e7018-a2d1-45fd-a1ce-78efe4c96c33').bothE().hasLabel(startsWith('live_at_'))
.elementMap().toList()
```

List all `edges` start with the label `live_at_`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, We need to use `startingWith()` instead of `startWith()`

```
g.V('6b4e7018-a2d1-45fd-a1ce-78efe4c96c33').outE().hasLabel(startingWith('lives_at_'))
.elementMap().toList()
```

Comment: In the Azure Version of Gremlin - we use

Answer (score 0):

In Azure's version of Gremlin - we use in the following way

```
.has('someattrname', TextP.startingWith('xyz'))
```